# XML FirstChild.Childnode - Not understanding Nodes

Tags: xml, nodes, actionscript-2

I am trying to get the title of the NYP XML feed. So I load the XML address into a var and then try to access the first title:

```
title = _global.doc.firstChild.childNodes.childNodes[3].childNodes[0] + "";
```

As per the image:

Yellow Arrow is my `firstChild`
Orange Arrow is my `childNodes`
Black Arrow is my `childNodes[2]` (meaning third `<item>` node)
Grey Arrow is my `childNodes[0]` (meaning the `<title>` node)

Am I not understanding something correctly?
[image: Image with Arrow]

Comment: Using your commment I tried: title = _global.doc.firstChild.childNodes.childNodes[8].childNodes[0] + ""; (I think nodes start at 0) I am still getting undefined.

Comment: You might consider XPath, it let's you quit counting child nodes, and jump to the node by name.